# Reset values within dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm using a dom-repeat in Polymer. The corresponding list includes an initial value that should be set whenever the list of the dom-repeat is reset. However, when the first element of the list keeps the same initial value, the value is not reset even though I completely empty the list before resetting it to the new value. Here's my minimum example:

```
<dom-module id="console-app">
  <template>
    <div id="command-selection">
      <paper-dropdown-menu id="command" label="Function">
        <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" selected="{{_commandIndex}}">
          <paper-item>A</paper-item>
          <paper-item>B</paper-item>
        </paper-listbox>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>
    </div>

    <div id="parameters">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_parameterData]]">
        <parameter-block name="[[item.name]]" initial-value="[[item.initialValue]]" ></parameter-block>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
      class ConsoleApp extends Polymer.Element {

          static get is() {
              return 'console-app';
          }



          static get properties() {
              return {
                  _commandIndex: {
                      type: Number,
                      value: -1,
                      observer: '_onIndexChange'
                  },

                  _parameterData: {
                      type: Array,
                      value: () => { return []; }
                  }
              };
          }

          _onIndexChange() {
              this.set('_parameterData', []);

              switch (this._commandIndex) {
                  case 0:
                      this.set('_parameterData', [
                          { name: 'AAA', initialValue: '111'},
                          { name: 'BBB', initialValue: '123'}
                      ]);
                      break;

                  case 1:
                      this.set('_parameterData', [
                          { name: 'CCC', initialValue: '112'}
                      ]);
                      break;

              }
          }
      }

      customElements.define(ConsoleApp.is, ConsoleApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

parameter-block:

```
<dom-module id="parameter-block">
  <template>
    <paper-input id="non-bool-value" label="[[name]]"
                 value="{{_value}}"></paper-input>
  </template>

  <script>
      class ParameterBlock extends Polymer.Element {

          static get is() {
              return 'parameter-block';
          }



          static get properties() {
              return {
                  _value: {
                      type: String,
                      value: () => { return ''; }
                  },

                  initialValue: {
                      type: String,
                      value: () => { return ''; },
                      observer: '_onInitialValueChange'
                  },

                  name: {
                      type: String,
                      value: () => { return ''; }
                  }
              };
          }



          _onInitialValueChange() {
                this.set('_value', this.initialValue);
          }
      }

      customElements.define(ParameterBlock.is, ParameterBlock);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

When the index of the dropdown menu changes I reset _parameterData to [] and would assume that after that all future changes to _parameterData are evaluated as new elements. However, it seems like the list remembers the previous initial value after all as the corresponding listener is not called and previous changes to the first text element don't reset to 111 even though I'm changing the selection. If I use different initial values everything works fine, so I assume that I need to tell Polymer somehow to properly reset the elements, but how?

Comment: Here  is the plnkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/IhX5oIOslskGMqqsW4A4?p=preview ? Can you elaborate what is going wrong?

Comment: @Ofisora Thanks for that link! When I do the following steps:
- Select A in dropdown
- Change the first textfield to 12345
- Select B in dropbox
The content of the first textfield remains 12345 and does not reset to 111. I assumed, since I reset _parameterData to [] before setting it to the new values, I'd create new parameter-block objects, that have their initialValue initialized to '' and then changed to '111'. This would trigger the function _onInitialValueChange. However, this does not happen and the text remains the same, in our case 12345.

Comment: Did you try Ofisora's link? Or, did you try different browsers to see if your problem can be reproduced?

Comment: @FrankR. The link works fine, yes. However, it already has the solution implemented, so you cannot reproduce my problem there. I had the problem with multiple browser. But as I understood, it is not intended to completely reset elements within polymer and my wanted solution was not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you were only observing the `initialValue` the application will not know that the `initialValue` you were changing is for different `name`. That is why it is not resetting to default values you assigned.

You will need to observe both properties `name` and `initialValue`. So, change your observer code to :

```
static get observers() {
    return [
      '_onInitialValueChange(name, initialValue)'
    ]
}
```

and your method to:

```
_onInitialValueChange(name, initialValue) {
    this.set('_value', this.initialValue);
  }
```

I have updated the [plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/IhX5oIOslskGMqqsW4A4?p=preview) provided.

Comment: So, it does not matter that I set the array to [] before reinitializing it? I was thinking this would force a complete reevaluation. I would prefer a way to force this reevaluation as it is possible in my complete implementation that name and initial value are equal. And in those cases I want to reset the initial value as well. So, I'd basically want to destroy all existing parameter-blocks (I thought to do that by setting the array to []) and then create new ones that do not consider the previously set values but the starting values given in the properties. Is that possible?

Comment: You need to observe the `_parameterData` array and if any changes happen it will call that method and do your stuffs there.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks for your help! Even though I would have prefered some way to reset the elements.